# Unable to restart jenkins on 8080 after restarting droplet

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I am totally new to jenkins and CI/CD and I am using ubuntu 20.04 on digitalocean droplet server. When Jenkins was automatically restarting after installing nodejs plugin, I rebooted the droplet server and now I am getting below issue:

```
● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-05-22 15:20:08 UTC; 15s ago
    Process: 2402 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2402 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 22 15:20:08 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-intel-blr1-01 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counte>
May 22 15:20:08 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-intel-blr1-01 systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
May 22 15:20:08 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-intel-blr1-01 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 22 15:20:08 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-intel-blr1-01 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 22 15:20:08 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-intel-blr1-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.

root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-intel-blr1-01:/etc/default# sudo systemctl start jenkins
Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I have already tried "sudo systemctl restart jenkins" but it shows the same error. Any help or  suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me using a cloud instance with Jenkins version 2.361.2-1.1. I removed jenkins using yum `sudo yum remove jenkins` and cleaned systemctl service `sudo systemctl reset-failed`.

Then I downgraded jenkins using sudo yum install jenkins-2.346.3-1.1 (which was a version that worked for me in another cloud instance) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

What got me solved, on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS:
I tried:

1. `systemctl restart jenkins`
2. `systemctl start jenkins`
3. restart pc
4. find out if jenkins port is used.

Solved: `sudo update-alternatives --config java`, where i choose `java-11-openjdk`. After this, i just start the service.